# Using children states in Angular 2 router throws error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Heres my router config:

```
import { RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

...

export const AppRoutes : RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'myview',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'myview',
    component: ViewComponent,
    children: [{
      path: 'hello',
      component: HelloComponent
    }]
  },
];
```

When I try to load the page I get the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''
```

However, when I make the child route a sibling, like this:

```
export const AppRoutes : RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'myview',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'myview',
    component: ViewComponent
  },
  {
      path: 'hello',
      component: HelloComponent
    }
];
```

I am able to load the page fine without any errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because the way you have designed it is on initial load it is landing on `ViewComponent` component but `ViewComponent` has child so have to redirect to inner component.

You need to add one more route to children `routes` which will redirect `''` to `hello` component.

```
export const AppRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'myview', pathMatch: 'full'}, 
  { path: 'myview', component: ViewComponent,
      children: [
        { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'hello' }, //added redirection to hello
        { path: 'hello', component: HelloComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

> **Note:** Make sure you have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `myview` component HTML so that child route view can be shown
>   correctly.

Comment: why does the first child have a path set to an empty string? This is making my app redirect automatically to the `HelloComponent` from the page root.

Comment: how you want it then?

Comment: I have a link in the home component that sends me to `ViewComponent`. I then have a link in `ViewComponent` that goes to `HelloComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using any route for `''` in your RouterConfig.

As after redirect the new path will be `https://yourdomain/myview/`. And for this you have only created `https://yourdomain/myview/hello` route in routeCofig

I have created an app in angular 2. You can check the source [here](https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet/blob/master/Angular2StarterApp/Angular2StarterApp/) on Github.

Just add following line to your children path array:

> `{path: '', component: HelloComponent }`

Check [hero.routes.ts](https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet/blob/master/Angular2StarterApp/Angular2StarterApp/app/components/hero/hero.routes.ts) and [dragon.routes.ts](https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet/blob/master/Angular2StarterApp/Angular2StarterApp/app/components/dragon/dragon.routes.ts) files they will help you understand routing more clearly. Hope it will help. Thank you.